# Calling "add all missing imports" from VScode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to trigger VSCode "add all missing imports" from an extension. Is it possible?
If so, how?

[image: Code Action]

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Im using Typescript/Javascript

Comment: I did not quite get your question. Do you want an extension which has this feature of importing all missing ones to workspace?

Comment: Basically, VSCode has "add all missing import" code action, built in within the IDE (probably coming from Typescript Language Service). I would like to trigger that from the extension in writing

Answer (score 1):

Until the most recent version for Linux (1.33.1) this option isn't available on "File" -> "Preferences" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts" window.

Unfortunately, you have to do it manually by clicking the helper icon or typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to show fixes options =/

Comment: In Mac OSX `Cmd` + `.` works to displaying the context menu with those options to choose from using the arrows. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke it by calling the following command:

```
_typescript.applyFixAllCodeAction
```

with arguments:

```
[document.fileName, { fixId: 'fixMissingImport'}]
```